# How do we separate H2O from CO2?

Tags: separation-techniques

Let's say I have a mixture of $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ gases. I've read that $\ce{CO2}$ is heavier (molar mass is $\pu{44.01 g/mol}$) than $\ce{H2O}$ (molar mass is $\pu{18.02 g/mol}$). So, if the mixture is supplied to a cylinder from the bottom, will only the water vapour reach the top? If so, is this a good way to separate the $\ce{CO2}$ and water vapour? Or is there a more efficient way to separate them?

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: What you propose does not work at all. Never.

Comment: @Karl Then, could you please write an answer for a better solution to this problem?

Comment: It is hard to see any source containing a mixture of CO2 and water as *gasses*. Most likely under normal conditions you would have water liquid under an atmosphere of carbon dioxide (with the water saturated with CO2). Or a stream of hot gases containing both. What circumstances are you considering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what equipment you have available.  A mix of compression and cooling will work much better than relying on their molecular weights.

Water boils at 100 degC, while CO2 sublimates at -78 degC.  Simple cooling will ensure that water condenses long before the CO2, while compression will drive the formation formation of water-water bonds. The [Clapeyron equation](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Physical_Chemistry_(Fleming)/08:_Phase_Equilibrium/8.04:_The_Clapeyron_Equation) should let you calculate the needed values.

Answer (score 4):

Separation of $\ce{H2O}$ from $\ce{CO2}$ has been done by all analytical chemists in the $19$th century, when they had to determine the formula of a new organic compound X.  The compound X was mixed with some $\ce{CuO}$ powder, introduced in a horizontal glass tube and heated by a burner in an oxygen current. X was burned int $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$.  Then the oxygen gas current containing some $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ had to cross another glass tube filled with pieces of anhydrous calcium chloride $\ce{CaCl2}$ which fixed the water vapor, producing $\ce{CaCl2·6H2O}$. The $\ce{CaCl2}$ tube was weighed before and after the operation. The increase in weight gives the total amount of $\ce{H2O}$ in the mixture of gases.

Then the gas was sent to bubble through a concentrated $\ce{NaOH}$ solution, where the following reaction happened $$\ce{CO2 + 2 NaOH -> Na2CO3 + H2O}$$ The $\ce{NaOH}$ solution was weighed before and after the operation. The increase in weight gives the total amount of $\ce{CO2}$ in the gas.